# In flutter How to add a list to another list, how to delete, and recall the data?

Tags: flutter, dart

**To make my question clear:**
I work in meals page layout and the idea is the user will select the food item of his/her meal from a list by click on a checkbox, and after that add meal in the system.

**Question is:**
I need to create a list (growth list) that contains all the food item information that the user is select it and after the user is press "add" button I will save each single food item' information from list to the database. I try to match ways but it not work. and I don't understand the wrong. I try a list and the problem is was how to callback the single food item's information. After that, now I try nested list and the problem is was how to insert or add the food item's information to a list.

**here a code of nested list:**

```
List<List> food= [];
```

add when click on checkbox:

```
List foo=[widget.id,widget.name,widget.carbs,widget.Amunt];
//when try with insert:
food.insert(index, foo);
//when try with add:
food[index].add(foo);
```

remove:

```
food.removeAt(index);
```

callback:

```
for(int i=0;i<food.length;i++){
   Item vat= Item(food[i][0],mealId, dbEmail,food[i][1], food[i][2], food[i][3]);
   var dbItem= await helper.insertFood(Item);
                    }
```

**here an old code of list:**

```
List food;
```

add when click on checkbox:

```
List foo=[widget.id,widget.name,widget.carbs,widget.Amunt];

 varty.add({ 'id':widget.id,'name':widget.name,'carb':widget.carbs,'amunt':widget.Amunt});
```

remove:

```
food.removeAt(index);
```

callback:

```
for(int i=0;i<food.length;i++){
   Item vat= Item(food[i]['id'],mealId,dbEmail,food[i]['name'],food[i]['carb'],food[i]['amunt']);
   var dbItem= await helper.insertFood(Item);
                    }
```

I think there's something I didn't use the right way but I don't know what it is!
So, I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: you should use List<Map>  like this : List <Map > food = [ { 'food1 : 'meals' '} , {'food2 : chicken} , .... ]